# Prevent PyInstaller Splash Displays Imports

Tags: python, pyinstaller, splash-screen, auto-py-to-exe

How can I prevent such statements (import statements that are used in my code by the code itself or another module) from being shown on the splash page? I am not looking for it to be disabled as I do update it within my code, but just looking for it to not display the imports. Using the following expression to compile

python -m PyInstaller --clean --noconfirm grinch_bot.spec[image]

I tried a couple of flags such as --noconfirm however did not have any luck